# Page.User.Identity.Name returns email instead of username

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Working on a legacy .NET web forms app for the past few weeks. For as long as I've been working on it Page.User.Identity.Name has always returned the authenticated user's username. Today it started returning the user's email and I have no idea what changed. An internet search found that it gets set when FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() (or maybe FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()) is called. After stepping through the code I am most definitely passing the username into both of these methods but when I check the value of Page.User.Identity.Name on the homepage it still comes back as email.

Comment: Is this occurring for all users, or just one user? Maybe that user name used is a email?